# Retrieve latest timestamp in table

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I've a table with primary id and timestamp fields and there are many rows with different timestamps. I want to retrieve the row for which the latest timestamp is there for a specific id. The timestamp is in UNIX timestamp format.
How do I retrieve that specific row?

Comment: Show some sample data and expected output from that.

Comment: <code><pre>id     timestamp

1      3230313530333330313231313131
2      3230313530323131313633313339
1      3230313530323037313733363534
3      3230313530313237313232363035
2      3230313530313135303530323432
1      3230313530313135303435383334
</code></pre>

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, max(timestamp)
from table 
group by id
```

Hope helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
select * from table where id=1 order by timestamp_field desc;
```